# Websphere 7 - How to know EARs ports deployed in the same Server Instance

Tags: java, websphere, ear

I'm currently deploying 2 EARs in the same Server Instance. The first one can be accessed in the port 9081, but the second one can't. Is there any way to know in which port I can get access to the second one? I've been trying to look it up in the Administrative Console but got nothing so far.

Comment: All ears are by default accessible via same port. Ensure that your application is started, and if it is mapped to the default_host. Also check SystemOut.log for any error messages, and add error message you are receiving to your question.

Comment: check which host it is mapped with, and then check port for that host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both applications deployed to same Server the port should be same. Confirm from console if application is started and mapped to correct virtualhost. if started fine then please check SystemOut.log for any error when trying to access the application.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I thought they were going to be in different ports! :(